# Help proving $T$ and $S^{-1}TS$ have the same eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need help in Linear Algebra Done Right, section 5.A, problem 15a:

> Suppose $T \in L(V)$. Suppose $S \in L(V)$ is invertible.

> (a) Prove that $T$ and $S^{-1}TS$ have the same eigenvalues.

**Note:** In this chapter, all vector spaces are assumed to be finite-dimensional over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

I've found that if $x$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$, $S^{-1}x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$, so all eigenvalues of $T$ are eigenvalues of $S^{-1}TS$, but I need help proving in the other direction.

My Proof:
Because $Tx=\lambda x$, $S^{-1}TS(S^{-1}x)=S^{-1}Tx=S^{-1}\lambda x=\lambda S^{-1}x$. Since $S^{-1}$ is invertible, $S^{-1}x\neq 0$. So $S^{-1}x$ is an eigenvector of $S^{-1}TS$.

Could you help me?

Comment: What help are you looking for?

Comment: Looks fine so far. You've shown that the set of eigenvalues of $T$ is a subset of the set of eigenvalues of $STS^{-1}$. Now you need to show the reverse inclusion.

Comment: My favourite proof is that $T, STS^{-1}$ represent the same linear map in a different basis.

Comment: @AlohaSine I really wish more introductory linear algebra texts and courses worked from the angle that vectors and linear transformations exist without coordinate grids, and matrix representations only appear once you impose coordinates. Is that better for learners? I don't know. But it would ultimately result in a healthier mental model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have proven that any eigenvalue of $T$ is an eigenvalue of $S^{-1}TS$. It remains to go the other way.

Hint: $x\mapsto S^{-1}x$ successfully took you one way. It would make sense that $y \mapsto Sy$ takes you the other way. (You may need to rewrite $T$ a little.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\det(tI-S^{-1}TS)=\det(S^{-1}(tI-T)S)=\det(tI-T),$$we have that $T$ and $S^{-1}TS$ have the same characteristic polynomial (and hence the same eigenvalues, which are its roots).

Comment: Perfectly valid, of course, but this may not be a suitable proof for this context: Axler's LADR doesn't cover determinants until the last chapter (10 or so), whereas this problem is from chapter 5.

Comment: Oh. I had heard about that book doing things in an arguably weird order, but I didn't think that determinants came that late. Wow. Anyway, OP is essentially done with the proof since he proved that eigenvalues of $T$ are eigenvalues of $S^{-1}TS$ for *arbitrary* $S$ and $T$, so the "converse" they want follows by replacing $S$ and $T$ with $S^{-1}$ and $S^{-1}TS$, respectively.

Comment: @leoli1 Axler assumes finite dimensionality throughout this chapter: "Now we begin our investigation of linear maps from a finite-dimensional vector space to itself." I've edited the question to mention this.

Comment: @IvoTerek Yeah, Axler's book is unconventional and determinant-phobic. Just checked: he doesn't cover the characteristic polynomial until chapter 8, and he does it without determinants, which aren't covered until chapter 10 (where he *defines* the determinant of a linear operator as the product of its eigenvalues!)

Comment: I see. If he had a vector space over an arbitrary field, what would he do? Extend the scalars to the splitting field of the characteristic polynomial via tensor product, show that the characteristic polynomial remains the same, define the determinant to be the product of the roots there, and then show the result lies in the original field? Or something like that? Oy vey.

Comment: @IvoTerek You should still be able to calculate the characteristic polynomial via calculating the annihilator polynomial of $T$ on some nonzero vector, taking the quotient by the cyclic subspace, and recursively calculating the characteristic polynomial of $\bar T$ on the quotient and multiplying; and then, the determinant would be $(-1)^n$ times the constant coefficient of the characteristic polynomial.